# Trying to produce code for average and sum C++

Tags: c++, math, sum, integer, average

I am trying to produce code with an output of:

```
Enter six fp numbers on a single line, separated by spaces: 1.5 2.1 3.8 4.2 5.7 6.1ENTER
Sum of 1.5 + 2.1 + 3.8 + 4.2 + 5.7 + 6.1 = 23.4\n
Average = 3.9\n
```

I started C++ a day ago so I literally don't know what I'm doing. This is the script I currently have. I know there are some punctuation errors.

```
    #include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main () 
{
   int num1;
   int num2;
   int num3;
   int num4;
   int num6;

cout << "Enter six fp numbers on a single line, separated by spaces: ";
  cin >> num1 >> num2 >> num3 >> num4 >> num5 >> num6 << endl;
```

How do I avoid issues listing numerical values and how do I insert a sum and average function? Any help would be appreciated thank you.

Comment: `int` isn't going to work for floating point numbers. You need to use `double` or `float`. You might consider using an array or a `std::vector` to hold the values, it makes the task much easier.

Comment: Having a set of variables with sequential names (like `num1`, `num2`, ....) indicates that you need to use an array (e.g. `int num[6]`) or - in modern C++ - a standard container (e.g. `std::vector<int> num(6)`).   To add up values in an array, options include a simple loop (e.g. `int sum = 0; for (i = 0; i < 6; ++i) sum += num[i];`) or use a standard algorithm `int sum = std::accumulate(std::begin(num), std::end(num), 0);`.  To calculate an average, convert `sum` to `double` and divide by the number of elements (e.g. `double avg = double(sum)/6;`)

Answer (score 1):

I'll give you this much as a way to get started.  This just computes the sum on the fly, rather than storing it in a vector, which is another great way t do this.

```
#include <iostream>
int main () 
{
    std::cout << "Enter six fp numbers on a single line, separated by spaces: ";
    double sum = 0.0;
    double f;
    for( int i = 0; i < 6; i++ )
    {
        std::cin >> f;
        sum += f;
    }

    std::cout << "Sum is " << sum << "\n";
    std::cout << "Average is " << (sum/6) << "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
Enter six fp numbers on a single line, separated by spaces: 1.2 3.4 5.6 7.8 9.1 2.3
Sum is 29.4
Average is 4.9
```

Answer (score 0):

What you did was just declare 5 integer variables, stored the numbers in them and simply calculated average there are some issues with that

```
1. The numbers you have stored are of the type float
2. There are simply better ways to do it but since you started with 
   C++ recently it is understandable
```

If you are not familiar with loops I suggest you read up on them but since we know the no of variables, a **for loop** would work fantastically here.

So what we can do is

```
#include <iostream>
int main () 
{
    std::cout << "Enter six numbers on a single line, separated by spaces: "; 
    
    double sum = 0.0,buffer;
    for( int i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) //For 6 iteration 0-5
    {
        std::cin >> biffer;
        sum = sum + buffer;
    }

    std::cout << "The sum of the Given nos is:-  " << sum << "\n";
    std::cout << "Average of the given nos is:-  " << (sum/6) << "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
Enter six fp numbers on a single line, separated by spaces: 1.2 3.4 5.6 7.8 
9.1 2.3
Sum of the Given nos is:-  29.4
Average of the given nos is:- 4.9
```

You can replace **6** with any number to make this program scalable

**Good Luck**